# How to get autogenerated files from specific directory with Bazel rule

Tags: bazel

When building an application based on Bazel, some files are created automatically.

The rule that creates these files comes from this repository:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-bazel

I am currently trying to add a wrapper that will convert the ProtoInfo structure from DefaultInfo.

DefaultInfo is being created as follows (source from above repository):

```
return DefaultInfo(files = depset([
    declared_dir,
]))
```

, so I have path to the directory, but I don't know what files will be generated.

Something like this would be a good solution if it worked properly:

```
ctx.glob([f"{output_directory}/*.proto"])
```

Summary, my question:

How to get autogenerated files from specific directory with Bazel rule at runtime?

My main goal is to get a ProtoInfo structure with list of generated files.

Answer (score 2):

I think he easiest way is to use `actions.run` to create a mappings file with the contents of said directory so that you can then feed it to bazel so that it can predeclare the outputs on subsequent runs. The only ways I know of to do this are deep in bazel's java code for their processing of outputs.

I often use something like [pip_parse vendored](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/tree/main/examples/pip_parse_vendored) to accomplish this when the outputs are generated on the fly and the names are not easy to predetermine when writing the rule.